# Multiple Touch Sensor

Tags: sensor

I am doing project for school: "Interactive Piano Highliter". One of the task is to check whether the key was pressed or not. Prototype consists of 20 keys, so I need 20 touch sensors.

Do you know whether I can combine [MPR121](https://www.mbtechworks.com/how-to/mpr121-capacitive-touch-for-raspberry-pi-project/) and [Touch Hat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wk76UPRAVxI) together? Do you think it will work out? I will have then 24 outputs, which amount is even exceeding.